# Iterate though list on each for loop iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'm working on the following code:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.....]
for x in range(0, len(mylist), 3):
    value = mylist[x:x + 3]
    print(value)
```

Basically, I'm taking 3 items in `mylist` at a time, the code is bigger than that, but I'm doing a lot of things with them returning a value from it, then it takes the next 3 items from `mylist` and keep doing it till the end of this list.

But now I have a problem, I need to identify each iteration, but they follow a rule:

The first loop are from A, the second are from B and the third are from C.
When it reaches the third, it starts over with A, so what I'm trying to do is something like this:

`mylist[0:3]` are from A

`mylist[3:6]` are from B

`mylist[6:9]` are from C

`mylist[9:12]`are from A

`mylist[12:15]` are from B......

The initial idea was to implement a identifier the goes from A to C, and each iteration it jumps to the next identifier, but when it reaches C, it backs to A.

So the output seems like this:

```
[1,2,3] from A
[4,5,6] from B
[6,7,8] from C
[9,10,11] from A
[12,13,14] from B
[15,16,17] from C
[18,19,20] from A.....
```

My bad solution:
Create `identifiers = [A,B,C]` multiply it by the len of `mylist` -> `identifiers = [A,B,C]*len(mylist)`
So the amount of A's, B's and C's are the same of `mylist` numbers that it needs to identify. Then inside my for loop I add a counter that adds +1 to itself and access the index of my list.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.....]
identifier = ['A','B','C']*len(mylist)
counter = -1
for x in range(0, len(mylist), 3):

    value = mylist[x:x + 3]
    counter += 1
    print(value, identifier[counter])
```

But its too ugly and not fast at all. Does anyone know a faster way to do it?

Comment: What are A, B and C ? 3 lists ? I don't really get what you're code is supposed to do.

Comment: Its just a string that i need to return bounded to the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cycle, zip, and unpack:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for value, iden in zip(mylist, itertools.cycle('A', 'B', 'C')):
    print(value, iden)
```

Output:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 A
5 B
6 C
7 A
8 B
9 C
10 A
```

Comment: Maybe it needs to do some reshape of my list before in order to get n rows and 3 columns (to exactly fit the expected result)? what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a generator to iterate over your identifiers:

```
def infinite_generator(seq):
    while True:
        for item in seq:
            yield item
```

Initialise the identifiers:

```
identifier = infinite_generator(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Then in your loop:

```
print(value, next(identifier))
```

Comment: Which is bascially the same as [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49134627/3941704) fitted for your problem.
You can first [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) your `list` into a `list of arrays` containing 3 elements:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
_reshaped = np.reshape(mylist[:len(mylist)-len(mylist)%3],(-1,3))

print(_reshaped)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Note that it works since your list contains multiple of 3 elements (so you need to drop the last elements in order to respect this condition, `mylist[:len(mylist)-len(mylist)%3]`) - [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/3941704)
See **UPDATE** section for a reshape that fits to your question.

Then apply Ignacio's solution on the reshaped list

```
for value, iden in zip(_reshaped, itertools.cycle(('A', 'B', 'C'))):
    print(value, iden)

[1 2 3] A
[4 5 6] B
[7 8 9] C
```

---

**UPDATE**
You can use [@NedBatchelder's chunk generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks/312464#312464) to reshape you array as expected:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

_reshaped = list(chunks(mylist, 3))
print(_reshaped)
    [[1 2 3]
     [4 5 6]
     [7 8 9]
     [10]]
```

Then:

```
for value, iden in zip(_reshaped, itertools.cycle(('A', 'B', 'C'))):
    print(value, iden)

[1 2 3] A
[4 5 6] B
[7 8 9] C
[10] A
```

---

**Performances**

*Your solution* : 1.32 ms ± 94.3 µs per loop
*With a reshaped list* : 1.32 ms ± 84.6 µs per loop

You notice that there is no sensitive difference in terms of performances for an equivalent result.

Comment: Thanks for the timing results, i was not expecting a big amount of difference, but as my main goal here is performance, because the final objective has been reached anyway, every improvement would be welcome

Comment: I'm using the generator from itertools with next(generator) function, it proved to be faster then what i was doing, i'm going to try your solution and see what is faster

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Generator for the slices:

```
grouped_items = zip(*[seq[i::3] for i in range(3)])
```